# ListPlot will not color markers in accordance with my color function

Tags: plotting, color

I have the following color table:

```
colTable = 
  {{Black}, Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, x]}, {x, 1/2000, 1, 1/2000}]}; 
colTable = Flatten[colTable];
```

I can color a list plot curve when the plot is joined, but not the plot markers when the plot is not joined.

The following code

```
plot = ListPlot[coordinates*dx, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &), Joined -> True, 
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 130*dx}, {0, 130*dx}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Thickness[0.002]}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y in mm", ""}, {"x in mm", imageDir}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 30, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 2000];
```

gives

[image]

Buy when drawing only the markers with this code

```
plot = ListPlot[coordinates*dx, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &), Joined -> False, 
   Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 130*dx}, {0, 130*dx}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Thickness[0.002]}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y in mm", ""}, {"x in mm", imageDir}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 30, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 2000];
```

I get:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

With the help example from – [J. M.♦](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m)  I get now the correct image below for plot markers, when using the following code:

```
 plot = ListPlot[MapThread[Style, {coordinates*dx, colTable}], 
   PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[15], Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 130*dx}, {0, 130*dx}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y (mm)", ""}, {"x (mm)", imageDir}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 30, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 2000];
```

[image]

By the way I have used this same color table and superposed corresponding images (I did not mention that the data are center of mass coordinates of circular shaped objects in CMOS images). Here I get the following image which corresponds to the plot with the markers:

[image]

**Question**: The color table is the same for the joined data points (curve, see top plot) and for the plot markers. So **I would assume for the curve at top the same color variation.** But it is not the case?

Comment: As I see it, you're coloring by the order of the points in the latter diagram, and by their abscissas in the former diagram. I might be able to come up with something, but to help us help you, please provide at least a subset of your data.

Comment: I have used DumpSave and saved the variable "data" to http://tinyurl.com/qceeuds
Thanks for looking into the data ...

Comment: Your data is unreadable for me; that may have to do with the fact that we do not have the same OS. I would suggest putting the data into something like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) instead.

Comment: Can you read that? http://pastebin.com/6YALzqwM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, as noted in the docs for `ListPlot[]`, "`ColorFunction` requires at least one dataset to be `Joined`." One can use `Style[]` instead to color the points, like so:

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, π, π/11}];
cols = ColorData["ThermometerColors", "BlendArgument"];

{ListPlot[MapThread[Style, {data, cols}], Background -> Black, 
          PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[4]], 
ListPlot[data, Background -> Black, ColorFunction -> (Blend[cols, #] &),
         Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4]]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: joined and disconnected]

Comment: Your solution is more than twice faster ... only one question/remark: the markers have grey sourrounding if I use white background? I used the following code: 
plot = ListPlot[MapThread[Style, {coordinates*dx, colTable}], 
    PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[10], Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 130*dx}, {0, 130*dx}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"y (mm)", ""}, {"x (mm)", imageDir}}, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 30, 
      FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 2000];

Comment: Not having your data, I can't reproduce that. What happens if you remove `Background -> Black` in my examples?

Comment: Now I tried your example data with white background and it looks good ...

Answer (score 7):

Make each point a separate data set by mapping `List` onto the data.

```
n = 36;
data = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, π, π/n}];
colTable = {{Black}, 
    Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, x]}, {x, 1/n, 1, 1/n}]} // 
   Flatten;

ListPlot[List /@ data, PlotStyle -> colTable]
```

[image]

Comment: Great ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {1000, 2}];
ListPlot[pts, ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &), Joined -> True,
   Frame -> True] /. Line[x__] :> {PointSize[0.02], Point[x]}
```

[image]